# Setting specific attributes for a linux terminal instance

Tags: linux, multiple-instances, linux-terminal

I recently started to use linux for programming because it feels more comforable than programming in windows, but i miss from windows a particular feature.

I would like to have two different terminal winows, one for compiling and one other for running console applications, that have different attributes. I would like to have one without scrollbar and with a specific font and the other as a normal terminal.

For now i know how to make every window have the same settings, but i whould like something as: *This window has always got to be green and, at the same time, another window has got to be purple and transparent*

I am using linux lite's xfce terminal. The title of the terminal window is "Linux Lite Terminal".

Excuse me for my bad english

Comment: Please provide the terminal name.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the relevant information within the question body

Comment: Your English is a lot better than some native speakers I know. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use that terminal emulator. But I have used some others. Configuring them can be tricky. Have a look at this link: [https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man1/xfce4-terminal.1.html#lbAK]

Check out the **ENVIRONMENT** and **FILES** sections. **ENVIRONEMNT** has a reference to basedirs from freedesktop.org. **FILES** references the terminalrc file, which is where you would set default preference.

Your alternate window would have their own terminalrc file, which you would then specify on the command line.

Good Luck!

Comment: and once i have modified the terminalrc file how do i apply the changes to the window?

Comment: You would call the terminal command with an argument to pount to the custom terminalrc file, or he color table. Each terminal emulator is different, so I can't say exactly.   
Alternately, you could open the window and manually change the settings in the drop down window. I do that in RedHat.

Answer (score 1):

Some terminal emulators (including, but not limited to: gnome-terminal, roxterm, tilix, terminator, konsole) support "profiles" which is exactly what you're looking for. You can define multiple profiles, each having potentially different color scheme, font etc. You can easily switch the profile of any existing terminal, usually via its right-click menu.

Unfortunately xfce4-terminal doesn't support profiles. While Scottie H provided a nice workaround by specifying different config files at startup, this approach might be a bit cumbersome to configure and use. From each terminal, you can only modify its own configuration and not the other ones. You need to specify the "profile" when the terminal is started (no run-time change), and tabs of a window cannot have different settings.

I recommend that you try some of these aforementioned terminal emulators to get a feeling how profiles work, and based on that decide whether it's worth it for you to switch to another emulator, or you'd prefer to stick to the one you're already familiar with.